# How to show significant p Values in an R graph

Tags: r, plot, p-value

I plotted some of my data which is in this format

```
Time    SD  Average Situation   n   se
```

And I used this code

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=Time, y=Average, colour=Situation)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Average-se, ymax=Average+se), width=.1) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()
```

I want to do a T.test between the Exp and Control and I want to show significance in the graph using asterisks `*`. I am having a hard time looking for a code that does this. I know how to do a normal T.test but I really want those graphs that have asterisks to show significance.

Comment: I cannot answer for ggplot, as I do not use it... but in base R you would use the `text` function.

Comment: So how do I edit my graph using Text function??

Comment: I am not sure if `text` works with `ggplot`... but essentially you just need `text(x,y,"my text")`. See `?text` for the complete help. Otherwise, save the plot as pdf, open in your favourite vector graphics program (mine is Inkscape) and tweak your graph there. More effective and allows you to compose larger figures much more easily.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** I have rewritten this in light of your comments to give an example which works for me:

Let's say you want to add the p-value from a t-test to your graph...

```
set.seed(1)
### data following OPs format
data <- data.frame(Time=seq(10),
                   Average=abs(rnorm(10)),
                   Situation=rep(letters[1:2], 5)
                   )
### get p value
pval <- t.test(data$Average[data$Situation=="a"],
               data$Average[data$Situation=="b"])$p.value
### strip to 3 significant digits
pval <- signif(pval, 3)
### add asterisk if <0.05
pval <- ifelse(pval<0.05, paste0(pval, " *"), pval)
pval <- paste0("t-test \n p=", pval)

### plot as per OP
ggplot(data, aes(x=Time, y=Average, colour=Situation)) + 
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()+
### annotate it near lower left corner
    annotate("text",
             x=0.25*max(data$Time),
             y=0.25*max(data$Average),
             label=pval)
```

giving

[image]
See `?annotate` for more options. If you want a range of symbols for the p-value then you could modify it with a call to `switch` instead of `ifelse`.

A bigger question might be whether a `t-test` is appropriate for a time-dependent outcome...

Comment: I seem to be getting this error: Error in if (nrow(layer_data) == 0) return() : argument is of length zero

Comment: Yes, my fault. Error is due to not supplying `x` & `y` values for position of annotation - I mistakenly thought there was a default for these. Have edited above to reflect this. Should be OK now.

Comment: Cheers dude..but I got another error Error: Incompatible lengths for set aesthetics: label